# Maximum amount of concurrent users reached in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client

We keep reaching max concurrent users limit in Sitecore because of one specific user login. We see the user logged in 5 times so 5 sessions and we see it almost every day. This user does not have more than 2 browser tabs or browser sessions open at a time.

This user is not an admin but a content editor and has same roles as others. All other users show just one session on the KickUser screen.
We are on Sitecore 10.1

Any help/suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Deep

Comment: Check this if help - https://community.sitecore.com/community?id=community_question&sys_id=b5c5276d1b4770d0b8954371b24bcb52

Comment: Have you opened a support ticket?

Comment: Have not opened a support ticket with Sitecore but might do soon. I am not expecting them to respond for the next few days because of the long weekend.